# JavaScript converts ' into " when setting background-image

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to change the background image by JS with this line of code:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/bgone.jpg')";
```

Code runs and eventually, a style attribute is added to body:

```
<body style="background-image: url("img/bgone.jpg");">
```

The problem is it doesn't set, and that's because (I think) instead of wrapping the url in apostrophes, as I specified in my code, it does it in quotes which breaks it since the style attr uses quotes aswell. Any fix I could apply?

Comment: You've misidentified the problem. That is just the DOM inspector's view of the DOM.

Comment: The most likely cause of the problem is that the URL doesn't resolve to an image.

Comment: You can check if the image is properly loaded or not by using developer tools. For example, in Chrome. You can check that in the console. If the image is not loaded correctly, there will be an error telling you so

Comment: I have checked and there are no errors, in the Network tab it says the status is 200 OK for the file but I can't preview it while other images I can, so, something is not well there?

Comment: Actually I just noticed, in the network tab it says the type is 'text/html', not an image file like the others.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with single quote or escape double quote

```
<!-- use single quote -->
<body style="background-image: url('img/bgone.jpg');">

<!-- escape double quote -->
<body style="background-image: url(\"img/bgone.jpg\");">
```

Comment: They are writing JavaScript, not HTML … and if they were writing HTML then `\` wouldn't be an escape character.